# I entered one letter in java

Tags: java

How do I know if String letter is equal to char array

```
String[] choose = {"a","d","t","b","s","f","x"};
    String check;
    boolean error = false;

        System.out.print("Enter");

        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);    
         check = sn.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < choose.length;i++){

            if(choose[i] == check){
                System.out.print("you entered" + choose[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

What I did is this it didnt confirm I input letter a but "you entered" didnt show up.

Comment: [how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot test strings for equality using `==`. That only compares references (memory addresses). You need to use [`String#equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). In general `==` is most certainly what you **don't** want if you are testing for equality, **unless** you are checking to see if two variables are pointing to the *same* instance. This is rarely the case, since you are *usually* interested in testing *values* for equality.

So what you need to do is:

```
if(choose[i].equals(check)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare strings with ==, which only compares the references, but not the values. What you want to use is

```
if(check.equals(choose[i]))
```